# I dont understand why i get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 2 error

Tags: java, automata

I am trying to make a program that does cellular automata in 1D. For that, i need to read three variables from a single line. one of the variables, "L", determines the array length of "currentGeneration". However I get the ArrayIndexOut... error. I think this has to do with the dimension of my array and the variable L.

```
public class Cellulitissss {
    int L;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Boolean[] currentGeneration;
    String automaton;
    int G;
    String X;
    String Z;

    public void readGeneral() {

        String[] values = new String[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            values[i] = sc.next();
        }
        automaton = values[0];
        X = values[1];
        Z = values[2];
        L = Integer.parseInt(X);
        G = Integer.parseInt(Z);
        currentGeneration = new Boolean[L + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `values[i]` exists only for `i = 0,1` (size =2)

Comment: There is no index `2`,  your array has indexes `0` and `1` .

Comment: And look into your naming: names such as XLZG mean **nothing**. There is absolutely no good reason to use a single uppercase character as names for *anything*. Thus: read about java naming conventions, and start practicing that.

Comment: L and G was given for the assignment, X and Z are definitely unnecessary. thanks for the feedback. btw also SOLVED. Thanks all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tried to access values [2] which is wrong because array index starts from 0 so an array storing 2 values will store them at locations a[0] and a[1] if a is your array name. So trying to access a[2] will give an array index out of bounds exception